# Adding NSExceptionDomains into Info.plist for WKWebView with Xcode 8 and iOS 10.3

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, wkwebview

**Update:** The JS web requests also work from a `UIWebView`, just not `WKWebView`. But, I need the WK version for JS interop communication.

I've been trying and failing to get external JS requests to work within a `WKWebView` on Xcode 8 and iOS 10.3 to access the Dark Sky API. Everything I've tried gives me the same cross-scripting access errors (I've trimmed out details of the URL string being used):

```
[Error] Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.darksky.net/... due to access control checks.
```

My `Info.plist` contains this snippet, which seems correct based on much searching (the "insecure" setting should be irrelevant here, since I'm using HTTPS):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>darksky.net</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

I've tried all sorts of variations of settings in the internal dict and in the outer dict (even tried adding the awful `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`, to no avail).

The exact same JS code works from an Android `WebView` with basic security settings toggled and with `curl`, so I know it's not a problem with the Dark Sky API endpoint.

I see a bunch of other SO answers that seem to indicate to use what I have in my `.plist` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289712/nsexceptiondomains-xcode-8-not-working)), but these don't seem to do the trick.

Any ideas what magic iOS voodoo I'm missing here?

Comment: Are  you saying `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` does not work for you either?  Also, when I [do a "`openssl s_client -connect api.darksky.net:80`" in the Terminal](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/100035), I see TLS is actually `TLS1.2`.

Comment: Correct, arbitrary loads don't work either. I tried updating to TLS1.2 and that also did not work.

Comment: Looks like I can build the JS interop into UIWebView. But, it's annoying to have to switch over, given that Apple is encouraging everyone to use WKWebView.